# ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling a Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I have a problem with parsing a Parcelable across an Intent.

I create parcelable using

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra(ShoppingListAdapter.parcelName, la);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
```

I receive it in the onActivityResult:

```
Parcelable myData = data.getParcelableExtra(ShoppingListAdapter.parcelName);
```

Then pass it to another Activity using:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,Class.class);
myIntent.putExtra("myData", myData);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, RESULT);
```

My Parcelable has another Parcelable inside which I write and read uisng:

```
list = in.readParcelable(null);
```

I have tried using different class loaders, from ClassLoader.getSystemLoader() to MyClass.class.getClassLoader() but still I get a Runtime Exception:

```
06-12 21:13:04.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29962): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:
```

Is my Parcel corrupted somewhere before this or am I reading it wrong?

Alex

Comment: Are you trying to pass a ListAdapter implementation back as a result? (The variable name `la` looks suspicious to me. :))

Comment: Well yes and no. I am passing back the data held in the adapter. So it flattens various bits of data inside yes. It works for the configuration change where I do exactly the same thing but I stick it in to the savedInstance instead of Intent. Is that a problem? I thought I am just flattening the data inside thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out this was an incorrect approach to use. So although I haven't solved it, there is a better way of doing the same thing. So consider it instead

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

Although if anyone has any idea for the answer to the original question please post. Can happen somewhere else to someone else.

Alex

Comment: This is happening in my code.. Everything looks ok, but crashes when reading it back...

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem too, it's a silly thing. The **order and number** of the methods on writeToParcel and readToParcel should be the same and with the same variables.

I mean:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
   dest.writeString(title);
   dest.writeParcelable((Parcelable)this.getLocation(), flags);
   dest.writeString(value);  
}
```

must be in the same order as:

```
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in){

  this.setTitle(in.readString());
  this.setLocation((Location)in.readParcelable(android.location.Location.class.getClassLoader()));
  this.setValue(in.readString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was about to get mad.

Answer (score 0):

Does [Intent.setExtrasClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setExtrasClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29) help?